# How can I store the current time to my database when create button clicked?

Tags: c#, html, entity-framework, model-view-controller, crud

I am making a CRUD operations in MVC. I am also using Entity Framework.I am showing the user only 12 value of table(there is also currenttime(createDateTime) value which user cant see till they create). When I click the the create button. 
It should save the all values that I written on editor fields and also save the current time to database.

## Create View

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.languageID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-10"> 
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.languageID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.languageID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) 
   </div> 
</div>
```

## Controller

```
[HttpPost][ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "pkID,projectID,languageID,projectCompany,projectTitle,projectLink,projectText,projectImageURL,isPassive,createDateTime,createUsername,updateDateTime,updateUsername")] cusContentProjects cusContentProjects)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.cusContentProjects.Add(cusContentProjects);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(cusContentProjects);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    cusContentProjects.createDateTime = DateTime.Now; //Server current datetime
    db.cusContentProjects.Add(cusContentProjects);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: shoul I delete the values ? [Bind(Include = "pkID,projectID,languageID,projectCompany,projectTitle,proje‌​ctLink,projectText,p‌​rojectImageURL,isPas‌​sive,updat‌​eDateTime,updateUser‌​name")] cusContentProjects cusContentProjects)

Comment: @MertKaya not nessesory.

Answer (score 1):

use **UTC** values for date then parse to local based on UI requirement.
Storing the date Time in **UTC** format in db always give you an advantage of avoiding Date Time calculation mistake and time changes during day light saving days.

> DateTime.UtcNow

Comment: Its better to use with UTCNow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use DateTime.Now to get the current date

Answer (score 0):

You should get the dateTime from server, because getting it from the user's PC may not be the right date.

You can do it like this:

```
using System; //lib that allow you to use DateTime
...

[HttpPost][ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "pkID,projectID,languageID,projectCompany,projectTitle,projectLink,projectText,projectImageURL,isPassive,createDateTime,createUsername,updateDateTime,updateUsername")] cusContentProjects cusContentProjects)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.cusContentProjects.Add(cusContentProjects);
        var date = DateTime.now; //save it wherever you need
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(cusContentProjects);
}
```

Remember that the variable that you are saving DateTime need to be type DateTime too.

Hope it helps.
Good luck!